# React Router - never rendered directly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

in my react app routing is not working and it throws an error in the console. in my index file

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route } from 'react-router-dom';

<React.StrictMode>
    <Router>
      <Route path="/" element={<App />} />
    </Router>
  </React.StrictMode>
```

and in my App.js

```
import { Route, Routes, useHistory } from 'react-router-dom'; 

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
        {/* <DataProvder> */}
        <Sidebar />
        <Routes>
          <Route path='/' element={<Home />} />
          <Route path='/students' element={<Students />} />
          <Route path='/schools' element={<Schools />} />
          <Route path='/campus' element={<Campus />} />
          <Route path='/placement' element={<Placement />} />
          <Route path='/courses' element={<Courses />} />
          <Route path='/staff' element={<Staff />} />
        </Routes>
        {/* </DataProvder> */}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

When running this there is nothing to display, but in the console it throws this error:

```
Uncaught Error: A <Route> is only ever to be used as the child of <Routes> element, never rendered directly. Please wrap your <Route> in a <Routes>.
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Might sound obvious but have you tried by wrapping a `<Routes>` for your first route for `<App />`?. Something like this: `<Routes> <Route path="/" element={<App />}/></Routes>`

Comment: Are you 100% sure the `Route` definitions you have listed are the only ones in the app? Might be worth a full text search of your project of the string `<Route ` to double check. What you posted certainly loooks fine on the face of it so It makes me think theres more to it....hmm

Comment: @DrunkOldDog yes it's like that. i can edit the full App code

Comment: @AdamThomas Do i have to wrap the `<Route...>` in the `index.js` file?

Comment: Hah, yeh, I just posted that. Glad we led you to answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `<Route>` in `index.js` needs wrapping with `<Routes>`

Answer (score 1):

All `Route` components ***must*** be rendered by either a `Routes` component or another `Route` component in the case of nesting routes.

The `Route` in the index.js file is wrapped and rendered by the `Router` which is invalid. To resolve wrap it in a `Routes` component.

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';

<React.StrictMode>
  <Router>
    <Routes>
      <Route path="/" element={<App />}/>
    </Routes>
  </Router>
</React.StrictMode>
```

Or just render `App` directly since it handles rendering `Home` on path `"/"` for you.

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router } from 'react-router-dom';

<React.StrictMode>
  <Router>
    <App />
  </Router>
</React.StrictMode>
```